# Eager loading a polymorphic association with Kaminara pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, eager-loading, kaminari

I'm trying to eager load a polymorphic association while also paginating using the Kaminari gem:

```
@news_items = NewsItem.includes(:news_source).not_outdated
.where(:group_id => group_ids).order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

I'm getting the error message:

> ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError
>   in Pages#dashboard
>
> Showing 'BLAH BLAH'/dashboard.html.erb
>   where line #49 raised: Can not eagerly
>   load the polymorphic association
>   :news_source

When I remove the Kaminari scope ( .page[:page]).per(10) ), then the error disappears.

Anyone have any ideas?  [This article](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) suggests that eager loading with polymorphic associations is supported, but only if the conditions/order that might be applied to the Relation as a scope don't reference any other tables (if they do, then Rails uses the LEFT OUTER JOIN  method for the eager loading which can't work on polymorphic associations).  So: does Kaminari reference another table?

Would appreciate any advice!

Cheers.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the models?

Comment: Or maybe something like: Kaminari.paginate_array(@ news_items.all).page(params[:page]).per(10)

Comment: This question is more than 6 months on, and I think my code has well and truly moved on. Will try to have a peek back at it later today.

Comment: did you try  add includes(:news_source) to the end of you  expression?

Answer (score 0):

You should always use `preload` for polymorphic associations.

This error can happen because `includes` decides to call `eager_load` if it needs to query conditions on the association, and polymorphic associations are only supported by `preload`. It's in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/EagerLoadPolymorphicError.html)